# How use profiles with swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I want to set which profiles use to docker stack deploy. I mean, assume my docker-compose.yml is like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  admin:
    image: "${ADMIN_IMAGE}"
    restart: always
    profiles:
      - "admin"
  api:
    image: "${API_IMAGE}"
    restart: always
    profiles:
      - "api"
  redis:
    image: "${REDIS_IMAGE}"
    restart: always
    profiles:
      - "redis"
```

And want to deploy just admin and Redis services. If it was docker-compose, then I had two options:
`docker compose --profile=admin --profile=redis up -d`
or
`COMPOSE_PROFILES=admin,redis docker compose up -d`
but I want to deploy this as a swarm stack with `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stack_name` and I can't. Both options don't work in this situation, although docker docs [says swarm supports it](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#profiles), but [don't say how](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/).

So my question is:

- Do docker swarm support profiles?
- If it is supported, how I use it?
- Else, how can I deploy a part of compose file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems profiles are not supported yet in docker swarm. Using the `docker stack config` command on a `docker-compose.yml` file with profiles returns an error:

```
$ docker stack config -c docker-compose.yml 
services.my_service Additional property profiles is not allowed
```

For now the only workaround I figured out is to create different docker-compose.yml files for each profile I have, and `docker stack deploy` them into the same stack only when needed.

It's not a clean solution I know, just a workaround...